# react native--Cant fix unexpected TypeError (see screen shot)

Tags: react-native

I have this error in Scott Tolinski's (Level Up) React Native 4 Everyone video #12: TypeError: in this environment the sources for assign Must be an object.  iOS and Android doesn't work. How do I fix this? {--See Screen Shot--}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdpsd.jpg)

Comment: Can you show your AppContainer component ?

Comment: i dont know. I personally think it has nothing to ddo with the code. If you click the link and look at the screen shot, both Andropid and iOS is Bugging out and showing nothing @EQuimper

Comment: This is code I get that sometime. And this is inside your AppContainer

Comment: @Equimper I'm gonna look over it today. I think I'll just re write the whole thing over and hopefully I catch it. I just really want to stick to React Native, Sketch, and TensorFlow, I just hate running through snags like this in the middle of a tut then you cant get any help from the person who wrote the the tut, Sucks!

Comment: @EQuimper damn, You were absolutely right, it was something in the code (not sure what though). I went back and recoded everything from that section and I guess it was the way I had coded something in the <Container/> section of my code. Thanks